# How to round number to one decimal places python?

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to round my numbers to 1 decimal places. This could be with any number with many decimal places or no decimal places.
But now I'm trying to go with 8.25 as an example because when I try rounding it it always be cut or rounded to 8.2 but I'm looking for it to be 8.3 . Pls help

`print(round(result,1)) #result -> 8.2`

`"{:.1f}".format(result) #result -> 8.2 I was thinking about adding 0.05 to it and cut for 1 decimal place but I feel like it might affect the other number since it could be any number`

Comment: Not sure how adding `0.05` can affect the number, it should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use round().

```
result = 8.2546535
print(round(result,2))
```

Output

```
8.25
```

If you always want to round up you can use `math.ceil()`

```
import math
math.ceil(8.211234 * 10) / 10
```

Result

```
8.3
```

Comment: Im trying to round it to 1 decimal place but also make it 8.3 using round( x, 1) only make it 8.2

Comment: You can use math.ceil(), I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math    
def round_up(n, decimals=0):
        multiplier = 10 ** decimals
        return math.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier

print(round_up(8.25, 1))
```

output: 8.3

Comment: I'm trying to make it 8.3

Comment: I edited it, how about now?